# Get Event field picklist values for record type through API

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, record-type, ui-api

I need to get picklist values for some `Event` fields (namely `Subject` and a few custom fields) in my external application but only for a specific record type.

It seems the appropriate way to do this is to use the UI API (`/ui-api/object-info/{objectApiName}/picklist-values/{recordTypeId}`):
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values_collection.htm

But `Event` is not listed as a supported object and when attempting to use it, I get an `INVALID_FIELD` error code.

I've found I can get this information through the metadata API, but the requests take way too long, always 2+ seconds at a minimum.

What is the best way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Currently facing the same problem...  Unfortunately, a year and half later, there still does not appear to be an out-of-box "UI API" solution.

Your solution utilizing Apex and Metadata appears to be the best/only solution.